# Programmatically ship and comment single item of an order in Magento

Tags: magento

I know there is a way to programmatically invoice, ship, and set state on an order (http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/74072/), but I actually need to drill down even deeper to the item level of an order. We have a situation where, depending on item type, two different items can be processed in two different locations (from the same order). I can go into the Magento back-end and "ship" one item without "shipping" the other and append comments to that one item, but I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically. Thank you in advance for your help!

Update:
Here is the code I ended up using to accomplish this:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://somesite.domain/magento/index.php/api/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('username', 'password');

function extract_item_id($items, $sku ){
    foreach($items as $item ){
        if ($item["sku"]==$sku) {
            return $item["item_id"];
        }
    }
}

$orderNum = "200000052";

$oderInfo = $client->call($session, "sales_order.info", $orderNum );

$item_id = extract_item_id($oderInfo["items"], "someSKU") ;
$itemsQty = array( $item_id => "1" ); 
$shipment = array(
    $orderNum,
    $itemsQty,
    "Comment associated with item shipped.",
    true,
    true
);

var_dump($shipment);

$nship = $client->call($session, 'sales_order_shipment.create', $shipment);
```

Comment: This is a function achieved by ShipWorks - you may be able to download their Magento-specific PHP file which does this programmatically and hack away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never done it, but it looks like the SOAP API [supports creating individual shipment items](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/sales_order_shipment#sales_order_shipment.info).  That'd be the first thing I'd check.

If that doesn't work, I'd examine the source code the the Magento admin and reverse engineer what its doing with to create a single item shipment.  Specifically, start tracing at the `saveAction` of the admin's Shipment Controller

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/ShipmentController.php
```

The order/shipment/invoice section of Magento codebase is one of the most volatile/iterative sections, with the core objects/methods/dependencies changing subtly between versions.  Finding one "right" answer for this will prove difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. It looks like the SOAP API is definitely the right direction. The strange thing is that I used the sales_order_shipment.create method, and it only invoiced the item instead of shipping it. I wonder if I'm just missing something. Anyway, thank you for getting me on the right track.

Comment: What version of Magento are you using?  There was a recent Community Edition release that had an API bug that sounds like the behavior you're describing.

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/shipment-api-in-magento-1-4-1-broken/

Comment: I'm using Magento Professional. (Ver. 1.8.0.0)

Comment: Yep, just fixed the bug and it's working perfectly now! Thanks again!